# Не отображаются Rss Новости

Tags: xml, битрикс, rss

Компонент Новости настроен на экспорт RSS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при открытии этих новостей отдает такую страницу с XML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что может быть не так? может быть я что то не то делаю?

Comment: Это и есть rss структура новостей :) просто новостей у вас нет.

Comment: Добавил скриншот где видно что новости в инфоблоке есть

Comment: ну раз новости  есть - показывайте код экспорта в RSS, чтобы не устраивать очередной конкурс телепатов.

Comment: `<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
 "bitrix:rss.show",
 "",
 Array(
  "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
  "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
  "NUM_NEWS" => "10",
  "OUT_CHANNEL" => "N",
  "PROCESS" => "NONE",
  "URL" => "http://localhost/?rss=y"
 )
);?>`